# convergence of the series $\sum_{n≥ 1}\frac{(n+1)^n}{3^nn!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I want to determine the convergence of the series to do so, consider that $$\frac{(n+1)^n}{3^nn!}≤\frac{(n+1)^n}{3^n}$$

From where
$$\frac{(n+1)^n}{3^n}=\left({\frac{n}{3}}+{\frac{1}{3}}\right)^n$$

And how

$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\left({\frac{n}{3}}+{\frac{1}{3}}\right)^n}=\infty$ Then by the root criterion $\sum_{n≥ 1}\left({\frac{n}{3}}+{\frac{1}{3}}\right)^n=\sum_{n≥ 1}\frac{(n+1)^n}{3^n}$ diverges, and thus by the comparison criterion $\sum_{n≥ 1}\frac{(n+1)^n}{3^nn!}$ diverges

Am I right? or any suggestions? thank you.

Comment: Sequence or series ?

Comment: I already solved that problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not correct. Yes,$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(n+1)^n}{3^n}$$diverges, and, yes, you always have$$\frac{(n+1)^n}{3^nn!}\leqslant\frac{(n+1)^n}{3^n}.$$So what? It doesn't follow from this that$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(n+1)^n}{3^nn!}$$diverges.

You can use the quotient test:\begin{align}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{(n+2)^{n+1}}{3^{n+1}(n+1)!}}{\frac{(n+1)^n}{3^nn!}}&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n+2)^{n+1}}{3(n+1)^{n+1}}\\&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac13\left(1+\frac1{n+1}\right)^{n+1}\\&=\frac e3\\&<1,\end{align}and therefore your series converges.

Comment: You are correct, thank you for your help